# Who or what is Pyramid Head?

Tags: silent-hill-series, silent-hill-2

I've played almost the entire Silent Hill series, one of the games that impressed me the most is Silent Hill 2 not only by the twisted plot but by the most horrific antagonist, Pyramid Head. The thing with this character is that I never found out anything about it (him?), no motivation, no identity, nothing except that it wanted to kill me.

So as the title says, Who or What is Pyramid Head? (Either in Silent Hill 2 or the Silent Hill Series).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Silent Hill wikia](http://silenthill.wikia.com/wiki/Pyramid_Head):

> ...Pyramid Head is more than just a mere monster, seeing that he has
>   multiple incarnations and is frequently associated with feelings of
>   intense remorse and thus, the desire to face retribution for an
>   individual character's sin(s)....

According to Silent Hill 2's character designer, [Takayoshi Sato](http://www.webcitation.org/5vWYyUN3u):

> The place Silent Hill is used to be the place of execution, away from
>   cities. That was secret and sacred place. Heinous criminals are
>   transferred to that place and get executed. That place existed only
>   for that reason. Thus all village people are executioners or family of
>   executioners. Executioners needed to wear a mask at the event so they
>   do not directly witness their spear when it was piercing flesh. Time
>   have past, only memory of execution lingered, got enhanced and formed
>   the roaming illusion of Silent Hill. Pyramid head is distorted memory
>   of the executioners.

Similar to the other monsters in SH2 that represent James's guilt and desire for punishment (1), Pyramid head functions as (taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_Head#Analysis) which in turn references the official Silent Hill Strategy guide (2)):

> Pyramid Head functions as an executioner of Maria, a delusion of
>   James' who strongly resembles Mary. Through Maria's repeated deaths,
>   Pyramid Head reminds James of Mary's death and causes him to
>   experience guilt and suffering. His appearance as an executioner stems
>   from a picture that James saw while visiting the town three years ago
>   with Mary.

---

(1): "XXI: The World - Another World". Silent Hill 3 公式完全攻略ガイド/失われた記憶 サイレントヒル・クロニクル [Silent Hill 3 Official Strategy Guide / Lost Memories: Silent Hill Chronicle] (in Japanese). Japan: NTT Publishing Co., Ltd. 2003-07-31. p. 111

(2): "Silent Hill 2 Character Commentary". Silent Hill 3 公式完全攻略ガイド/失われた記憶 サイレントヒル・クロニクル [Silent Hill 3 Official Strategy Guide / Lost Memories: Silent Hill Chronicle] (in Japanese). Japan: NTT Publishing Co., Ltd. 2003-07-31. p. 46. ISBN 4-7571-8145-0.

Comment: I must say, amazing answer.